# Calling function from DLL injected into process and changing the addresses of the pointer functions

Tags: c++, c, dll

Hello I'm having this problem; I want to call functions from a process with my injected DLL, but I'd like to be able to change the address of the function since the addresses differ from each program version.

Basically I got DllMain resulting into making a new Thread which does the same as in this main example.

```
typedef void (*func_t)();
func_t func = (func_t)0x2000; //as an example

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int type = 1;

    if(type == 0) {
        *func = 0x2001; //altough *(int*)func = 0x2001; works but it doesn't change it
    }
    func(); //func will do the same in each version of the program except the addresses change so you can e.g change the type with cin >> type; and that'll it work
}
```

I get this: error: assignment of read-only location '* func

Thanks

Comment: What is the underlying problem? What makes you try to jump to absolute addresses?

Comment: Found the problem, I was trying to change a global variable from another file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
*func = 0x2001;
```

You probably want to do the opposite. change `func` instead of `*func` to the address of the function. For example this will work:

```
func = (func_t)0x2001;
```

Comment: Could anyone explain to me in why this would ever make sense?